# How to extend backroundcolour?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I need to spread the backround color of the "version" text shown in the picture to the left and right of the screen.

[image]

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
    
    class AyarlarSayfasi extends StatefulWidget {
      const AyarlarSayfasi({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _AyarlarSayfasiState createState() => _AyarlarSayfasiState();
    }
    
    class _AyarlarSayfasiState extends State<AyarlarSayfasi> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("SETTINGS"),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          body: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Version 1.0",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow, color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

In short, how can I make it look like in this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by trying :

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 40,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Version 1.0"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class AyarlarSayfasi extends StatefulWidget {
  const AyarlarSayfasi({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AyarlarSayfasiState createState() => _AyarlarSayfasiState();
}

class _AyarlarSayfasiState extends State<AyarlarSayfasi> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Ayarlar"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
            color: Colors.orange[200],
            child: Text(
              "Versiyon 4.7",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```